# reCAPTCHA.AspNetCore Validation is failing after upgrading asp.net core project from v2.2 to 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

After upgrading my asp.net core project from v2.2 to 3.1, recatcha.Validate(...) stop working as expected. I upgraded recaptcha v3 componente from v2.2.3 to 3.0.10, however, always the validating process is failing. Previous version was working fine.

[image]
[image]